# How to proceed with this SLAM implementation on an iRobot Create with Kinect?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not referring to a turtlebot. I have an iRobot Create (old one) and a Kinect connected to it. I am trying to use the kinect to generate a 2D map of the robot environment and later navigate the robot autonomously through it. I am new to ROS and was wondering if there are any tutorials that someone could suggest that describe a step by step process? If not, then can someone help me with defining an outline for how to proceed?

Till now I have this -

- A netbook with ROS Groovy running
- Installed the ros-brown-driver package for iCreate
- Currently installed the Turtlebot packages as well.

I am not sure how to proceed next. This is a very beginner question so I was hoping someone could help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108716/how-to-proceed-with-this-slam-implementation-on-an-irobot-create-with-kinect?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you have done the beginner tutorials.

I would do the tutorials in tf ( manages coordinate transforms)
http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials

There are some tutorials here
http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot

then have a look at the gmapping package, it will work with the create.
It uses a 2D laser scanner and wheel odometer which the create has.

There are packages to fake a 2D lidar using the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) with karma: 418 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-12-10**:
Like I mentioned. It's not the turtlebot. I have tried installing turtlebot packages and tried running but they don't work. I need help with respect to working with the irobot Create separately. I am having trouble starting off. I will check out the tf tutorials like you mentioned.Thank you for your reply!

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-12-10**:
The turtlebot packages will work with the old irobot-create. There are options in the configurations to change with mobility base you use

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-12-10**:
The kinect is giving me trouble as of now and I can't work it out.